# Write a specific part of a .txt file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

**EDIT** I am not actually using a .txt file as a preferred method to store valuable data. **This question is focussed on *writing to a specific part of a .txt file***

I'm using a .txt file as a dummy database for testing a program, and I came across the issue of re-writing a certain bit of data.

For example, the .txt file is as such:

```
Ben,welcome1,1
Frank,frankpassword,1
etc...
```

I'm using a simple method to retrieve the user information:

```
public void ReadUserFile(User_Model UModel)
{
    importFile = File.ReadAllText(fileName).Split('\n');
    foreach (string line in importFile)
    {
        data = line.Split(',');
        userName = data[0];
        password = data[1];
        accessLevel = Convert.ToInt32(data[2]);

        if (userName == UModel.UserName && password == UModel.UserPassword)
        {
            UModel.AccessLevel = accessLevel;
            if (UModel.UserPassword == "welcome1")
            {
                UModel.UserPassword = "change password";
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        else { UModel.UserPassword = "invalid"; }
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

And then I started writing a method to re-write the password if it was stored as 'welcome1', but when it came to it, I wasn't sure how to do it, or if it could even be done?

eg.

```
UModel.UserName = "Ben";
UModel.UserPassword = "welcome1";
UModel.ConfirmPassword = "newpassword";

public void UpdateUserFile(User_Model UModel)
{
    importFile = File.ReadAllText(fileName).Split('\n');
    foreach (string line in importFile)
    {
        data = line.Split(',');
        userName = data[0]; // "Ben"
        password = data[1]; // "welcome1"

        if (data[0] == UModel.UserName && UModel.UserPassword == data[1])
        {
            // Re-write "Ben,welcome1,1" to "Ben,newpassword,1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG! Are you seriously storing your username/passwords into a flat file without encryption? Please please please please replace all of that with an off the shelf user database library. If you endevour to use a CSV for your database, consider using [CsvHelper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/). But for the love of gawd! PLEASE USE A SALTED HASH FOR PASSWORD VALIDATION. If you don't know what a salted hash is, PLEASE just use a user database library!

Comment: How large is this filebased database going to be?

Comment: THIS IS ONLY FOR A TEST! I am not planning on keeping it this way. I'm just using it to test the functionality of the rest of my program.

Comment: A CSV file is just a string of text. If you want to rewrite a small portion of it it's possible by positioning to a specific character in the text and writing what you want, but if the new text is longer than the old you either have to move everything, or overwrite some of the existing file. It's generally easier to read the entire file, update it and write the entire file to disk. Or you use a database solution...

Comment: Test of what? One does not simply write a Random Access Write library with indexing. That is what RDBMSs are for! You can't figure out how to do what you want because there is no easy and efficient way to do it. But it occurs often enough that people have written software to abstract it.

Comment: This data storage is not essential to this program, I'm just using a .txt file instead of setting up a whole separate Db. I am merely writing this in so I can test how the *rest* of my program works together

Comment: @Ben, if this is for Faking (see Testing terminology), in my experience its actually just quicker to implement the Data-Layer in a code-first ORM. I typically use Entity Framework with SQL CE for this purpose.

Comment: @Aron I think I may need to look into the terminology, this has certainly flown a few warning flags for the wrong reasons. However again, I am not asking about the "database" I am asking about writing to a specific part of a .txt file, as the question title has pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 options based on how big your text file is:

1. If the text file is only supposed to be a few lines, use this solution:

   ```
   importFile = File.ReadAllText(fileName).Split('\n');
   StringBuilder newContents = new StringBuilder();

   foreach (string line in importFile)
   {
       data = line.Split(',');
       userName = data[0]; // "Ben"
       password = data[1]; // "welcome1"

       if (data[0] == UModel.UserName && UModel.UserPassword == data[1])
       {
           line = data[0] + "," + UModel.ConfirmPassword + "," + data[2];

           newContents.Append(line);
           newContents.AppendLine();
       }
   }

   File.WriteAllText(fileName, newContents.ToString());
   ```
2. If the text file is extremely huge, then you need to make use of 2 files.

Read line by line from one file, write it to another temp file line by line, till you find the matching line at which point you will write the modified line to the new file and then continue writing all the remaining lines as-is from the first file. Finally, you need to delete the old file and rename the new one to the old one.

Comment: +1 because you actually read the question! Thanks for the solution too, didn't think of this :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a dummy testing DB and performance isn't an issue, the simplest thing to do is to just read all the lines, modify them as necessary, and then rewrite the entire file from scratch. It'll be much easier than implementing in-place edits in what is essentially a linear file format.

If you really want to edit the file in-place, read up on using a [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamwriter) class to open the file as a FileStream, jump to the desired location, and write a line to it. This will probably require doing the original file reading with the accompanying `StreamReader` so you know the exact file position of the line to replace.

Answer (score 0):

its a simple program to update password according to your username .

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        string[] a = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/imp.txt");// to read all lines

        Console.WriteLine("enter a name whose password  u want to change");
        string g=Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter new password");
        string j = Console.ReadLine();
        for(int i=0;i<a.Length;i++)                  
        {

            string[] h = a[i].Split(',');
            if(h[0]==g)
            {
                a[i] = h[0] + ","+j+"," + h[2];
                break;// after finding a specific name,you dont need to search more 
            }

        }

        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:/imp.txt",a);//to write all data from " a "  into file


    }
```